# Give the two binary representations of $\frac{3}{8}$ and $\frac{7}{16}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently reading Chapter 2.5 of the book *Introduction to Real Analysis, 4th Edition* by Bartle and Sherbert, and in the exercises, I stumbled upon Exercise 12 which read:

"Give the two binary representations of $\frac{3}{8}$ and $\frac{7}{16}$"

I'm not really sure exactly what to do here. Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: What would you do, analogously, if you were asked for (more familiar) _decimal_ expansions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Here are two decimal representations of $\frac12:\;$  $0.5$ and $0.49999999...$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @the_ant_thologist:  it was just a comment (not a full answer) to get you thinking about how there could be two representations of one number; are you asking for two representations of $\frac38$ and two of $\frac7{16}$ or one of $\frac38$ and one of $\frac7{16}$?  the answers provided so far only satisfy the latter, though with the tag [tag:real-analysis] I would not be surprised if the former were intended

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: One for each fraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It boils down to the binary representation of the numerators since the denominators are powers of $2$:

$3 = 2 + 1 \implies \dfrac{3}{8}=\dfrac{2}{8}+\dfrac{1}{8}=\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{8} = 0.011_2$

$7 = 4 + 2 + 1 \implies \dfrac{7}{16}=\dfrac{4}{16}+\dfrac{2}{16}+\dfrac{1}{16}=\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{8}+\dfrac{1}{16} = 0.0111_2$

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{3}{8}=\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{8}=2^{-2}+2^{-3}=(0.011\bar0)_2$.

Try the other one.

Comment: Ahhh, I understand now. So, for $\frac{7}{16}$, it would be: $\frac{7}{16} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} = 0.0111$. Is this correct?

Comment: I would write $(0.0111\bar0)_2$ to be sure that nobody has doubts, but yes it is correct.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thank you.